# Styled-Components is giving an undefined component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components with react. When I tried importing my component into my App.js. It gives an Uncaught Error of an undefined component.

Here is my styled-component, Header.js:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as LogoSVG } from "./logo.svg";

export const Logo = styled(LogoSVG)`
  height: auto;
  max-width: 760px;
  width: 100%;
`;

export const Header = styled.header`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
`;

const HeaderComponent = () => (
  <Header>
    <Logo title="LavaLab Logo "/>
  </Header>
);

export default HeaderComponent;
```

Here is App.js where I import my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { GlobalStyle } from "./styles.js";
import HeaderComponent from "./Components/Header";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <HeaderComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

This is the updated error.
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have default in you export, try: `import  HeaderComponent from "./Components/Header";`

Comment: @red, thank you for pointing it out. I edited it but it is still showing the error in the console.

Comment: the error seems to pointing at  LogoSVG, are you sure of your svg path?

Comment: Yes, it was wrong.  I changed the correct path of SVG import. But now it is showing a different error. It said Cannot resolve dependency

Comment: The dependency error cleared. But it's still showing undefined error.

Comment: Provide an updated screenshot of the error

Comment: I updated the image. The error is similar to the previous one. It keeps referring to the logo declaration line.

Comment: Ok, to be sure that the problem is the logo, try to comment the logo and not include it inside header, print just a text.. if the error disappear you will be sure that you need to fix the svg import.

Comment: I've found that svg with CDATA inside has problem. Check your svg code, clear CDATA if presents

Comment: Yes, the error is confirmed to be from SVG. I checked the SVG but unfortunately, there was no CDATA in the SVG code.

Comment: `import LogoSVG from "./logo.svg";` maybe your bundler doesn't support import svg as components

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. But I'll read into it. I haven't checked anything about bundler. Thank you so much for your tips!

Comment: You can create SVG as a simple component then import to **HeaderComponent** compoent.